# Entity service query return true or false

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How would i get a simple query like so

```
from asg in context.assigmentGen
                            join agc in context.assignmentContact on asg.contact equals agc.contact
where agc.contact = "123"
```

how could I get this to return true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this? It depends though when you want it to return true or false :)

```
(from asg in context.assigmentGen
 join agc in context.assignmentContact on asg.contact equals agc.contact
 where agc.contact = "123").Any()
```

Comment: sure, glad I could help. If this solved your issue, you can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: was waiting for the timer to go away